# iPhone not appearing as a device in iTunes, making wireless sync impossible

Tags: macos, itunes, ios, wifi

I'm not sure when this issue started, but at some point in the past I was able to wirelessly sync my phone to my computer through iTunes.

The two things that I have changed recently are updating to Mavericks, updating to iOS7 and then getting a new iPhone. While I know I have never been able to wirelessly sync my 5s, I can't remember if my 4s was able to or not.

Now the only time I see my phone appear in iTunes is when I plug it into the computer.

I asked a guy at the genius bar, but he couldn't figure it out, though he wasn't familiar with the ability to sync wirelessly and had to ask around to figure out how it was supposed to happen.

Has anyone had this issue and solved it?

**Further Notes:**

I have "Sync with this iPhone over Wi-Fi" checked when I have the phone plugged in.

When the phone isn't plugged into the computer, but is plugged into a power source, and is on the same Wifi network as the computer, the phone does not appear as a device in iTunes.

Current version numbers:

iTunes 11.1.5 (5)

OSX 10.9.2

iOS 7.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS 7.1 update has fixed this issue.

Comment: I'm on the newest Mavericks and iOS and also can't see my phone. I'm on a 3rd cable, though certified nonetheless. Will give my Apple a go when I get my hands on it.

Comment: This question is about wireless syncing, but you might ask a new question if you aren't able to figure out your issue.